# Can I use Android Biometric to Authenticate 20+ Users

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, android-sdk, fingerprint

Is it possible to use a centralized biometric database with Android or am I limited to users having to create and register their fingerprints on the device lock-screen on each Android device?

I have an in-house built Android Application that I would like to use biometric authentication, instead of in-app passwords.

I'm looking at using something like a BioWolf 7 Device and potentially 20-30 different employees could use the device during a day.